# Who are 2B/37 better known as?

Tags: word

A quick pair of questions.

```
(a) Who are 2B/37 better known as?
(b) Who 'composed' 91π/216000?
```

*Source: GCHQ Puzzle book*

Comment: Are we looking for a single answer or is it two separate questions?

Comment: It is two questions.....

Comment: If they're not part of the same puzzle, they should probably be posted separately.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> 2B/37 (base 16) = 43/55 (base 10) = 43*4/55*4(base 10) = 172/220 (base 10) = AC/DC (base 16)

Comment: I think it is just 2 separate questions :D

Comment: So the real challenge is for the OP to accept both answers.

Comment: @MrLister I can't even tell which answer was first any more!

Comment: @Anush this answer was first by a little over a minute.  You can see exact timestamps by hovering over the "Answered X hours ago" text.

Comment: Is it weird that I'm bothered by the unnecessary conversion to base 10 and back? I mean, hex is just another format for representing integers... Then again, it does help make this answer a little more clear. +1 either way for the clever solution.

Comment: What an hard puzzle! How is anyone supposed to realize that it's base 16, or that another form of this number represents a person?

Answer (score 27):

For B)

> It was John Cage 
>  91 x (pi) / 216000 rad will give 4'33" 
>  John composed the piece 4'33"

Comment: If I can, I will give a $50$ rep bounty to this question and award you that :)

Comment: There we go :P ${}$

Comment: @user477343 Dude, you are such a nice person :)

Comment: Thank you! I don't mind about reputation, so I'm happy to give it away :)

Comment: Congratulations! $\boxed{\color{blue}{+100}}$

Comment: @user477343 Thank you very much! :D

Comment: No problemo! :D